# MIPS codes for MEAN, MEDIAN & MODE functions

Tags: arrays, mips, mean, median, mode

I've just starting learning **MIPS**. Can anyone please help me with the codes for finding mean, median and mode of an array? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.data
newline: .asciiz "\n"
total: .asciiz "Sum: "
mean: .asciiz "Mean: "
median: .asciiz "Median: "
mode: .asciiz "Mode: "
array:   .word 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5
         .word 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8
         .word 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10

length:  .word 30

sum:     .word 0
average: .word 0
    
.text
.globl main
.ent main
main:

#loop through the array to calculate sum

la $t0 array #array's starting address
li $t1 0     #loop index, i=0
lw $t2 length  #length
li $t3 0 #initialise sum =0

sumLoop:
lw $t4 ($t0)   #get array[i]
add $t3 $t3 $t4  #sum = sum+array[i]

addi $t1 $t1 1 #i = i+1
add $t0 $t0 4 #update array address

blt $t1 $t2 sumLoop

sw $t3 sum  #save sum

#printing sum

li $v0,4
la $a0, total
syscall

move $a0 $t3
li $v0 1
syscall

#calculate average

div $t5 $t3 $t2
sw $t5 average

#giving space of a line
li $v0,4
la $a0, newline
syscall

#printing mean statement
li $v0,4
la $a0, mean
syscall

move $a0 $t5
li $v0 1
syscall

#calculating median

la $t0, array 
lw $t1, length 
li $t3 4
div $t2, $t1, 2     #length / 2
mul $t3, $t3, $t2   #index*4
add $t4, $t0, $t3   #getting address of array[15]
lw $t5, ($t4)       #getting value of array[15]
sub $t4, $t4, 4     #getting address of array[14]
lw $t6, ($t4)       #getting value of array[14]
add $t7, $t6, $t5   #array[14] + array[15]
div $t8, $t7, 2     #median

#giving space of a line

li $v0,4
la $a0, newline
syscall

#printing median

li $v0,4
la $a0, median
syscall

move $a0 $t8
li $v0 1
syscall



#calculating mode

la $t0 array 
li $t1 0        #i=0
lw $t2 length  
li $t4, 1 
li $t6, 1 
li $t7, 0 
li $t8, 0   #modeValue
li $t9, 0   #modeCount

    Loop:
        lw $t5 ($t0)   #get array[i]
        bne $t4 ,$t5 , if

    previous:
        addi $t7 $t7 1  #counter++
        addi $t1 $t1 1  #i++
        add $t0 $t0 4   #next array address
        li $t4 ,0
        addi $t4 , $t5, 0

        blt $t1 $t2 Loop


#giving space of a line
li $v0,4
la $a0, newline
syscall


#printing mode statement
li $v0,4
la $a0, mode
syscall

move $a0 $t8
li $v0 1
syscall


li $v0 10
syscall
.end main



if:
    bgt $t7, $t9, update

next:
    li $t6 ,0
    addi $t6 , $t5, 0
    li $t7, 0
    j previous

update:
    li $t8 ,0
    addi $t8 , $t4, 0
    li $t9 ,0
    addi $t9 , $t7, 0
    j next
```

Comment: code works but gives wrong median when I kept my array length 5

Comment: The code for mean is for even array length as currently it is median = (array[length/2] + array[length/2 - 1])/2, for odd array length just make it to median = array[length/2]